# javascript syntax mismatch in firefox , IE

Tags: javascript, css

The following code works for firefox, but shows error in IE.

```
document.getElementById('zip_container').style.borderLeft = '1px solid #D9D9D9;';
```

where `zip_container` is a div.

Can anyone suggest anything on this.

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**invalid value** :

```
document.getElementById('zip_container').style.borderLeft = '1px solid #D9D9D9;';
```

when you modify style attributes using style.something, "`;`" is not necessary

but if you are modify it this way:

`document.getElementById('zip_container').style.cssText += ";border-left:1px solid #D9D9D9;";`

"`;`" can't be lost. So the correct way is:

`document.getElementById('zip_container').style.borderLeft = '1px solid #D9D9D9';`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('zip_container').style.borderLeft = '1px solid #D9D9D9';
```

(without the `;` inside the value)works everywhere.

When you set a attribute value via javascript, you set only the value. The `;` is a separator between different style definitions in an inline style. You need not (should not) provide it when changing an attribute with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add the complete code example so it get's clearer what your problem is, but as far as I can see now you might be out of trouble when you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.